# Is there a good resource for beautiful HTML forms?

Tags: website-design, forms

I am looking for some resources to design visually pleasing HTML forms. I can write the CSS, so even examples would be great.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Google about "beautiful HTML forms" there are so many perfect Examples for this situation..

Comment: Please note that "Brainstorming or idea gathering" are off topic [per the FAQ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you an idea:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/04/17/web-form-design-modern-solutions-and-creative-ideas/

There are few things to consider when re-designing form elements:

You need figure out if all of your form elements can truly be modified by CSS only. Some form elements can't be designed/changed (file browse element for example). You are pretty much stuck with browser default look/feel if your form has file browse input.

There are plenty of alternative methods to style form elements by using JavaScript plug-ins:

Though I would avoid relying on JS to re-style forms. Mainly because browser compatibility is always going to be problem.

I am not allowed to post more links but search **Smashing Magazine** with keywords 'form design' you get plenty of links.